# Flutter rest api https calling

Tags: flutter, api, https

```
  final url ="https://example.com/auth/individual/login";

  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: {"email": 'c@gmail.com', 'password': 'C@123'});

  print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  print(await http.read(Uri.parse('https://example.com/auth/individual/login')));
```

```
error:
Response body: {"message":"Cannot read property 'password' of null"}
Error: Request to https://example.com/auth/individual/login failed with status 404: Not Found.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
    at browser_client.BrowserClient.new.[_checkResponseSuccess] (http://localhost:50754/packages/http/src/multipart_request.dart.lib.js:618:17)
    at browser_client.BrowserClient.new.read (http://localhost:50754/packages/http/src/multipart_request.dart.lib.js:581:36)
    at read.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:40192:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:40062:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:34983:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:35551:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:35589:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:35437:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:35458:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
    at http://localhost:50754/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

I changed the api link to example.com this:
https://example.com/auth/individual/login

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? do you have the backend code? Do you have logs from the backend?

Comment: ya backend server is just crashing when i send. that's why it showing 404.and i tried double quotes rather than single not working. i tried on postman response is 200.but in flutter it's 404 why do you know any proper way to write it .

Answer (score 0):

In your body, try putting `password` in double quotes rather than single. I don't think many backends will accept keys with single quotes as it is not valid JSON.

Comment: ya backend server is just crashing when i send. that's why it showing 404.and i tried double quotes rather than single not working. i tried on postman response is 200.but in flutter it's 404 why do you know any proper way to write it .

Comment: If you're using Postman, click the </> symbol at the top right of your tab, then choose "Dart - http" to get the Dart code snippet you need. You might need to play with the response.statusCode check as not all apis are equal. Maybe just rip that statusCode check out during testing and dump the code to console. The code snippet from Postman works fine when POSTing to jsonplaceholder.typicode.com using your JSON **without** single quotes. Use one of the many JSON validator sites to ensure your payloads are valid. `{"email": 'c@gmail.com', 'password': 'C@123'}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: forget about postman i just testing there everything wors fine there.I want it to work on dart do you know what is the dart code it's always telling me this. {Response body: {"message":"Cannot read property 'password' of null"}}